# How to create a custom emoji keyboard in ios?

Tags: ios

I want to know how to create custom emoji keyboard in ios. I have tried to create it using stickerpack and imessages.And both were working properly in ios simulator.But When i run it on my device(iphone5s) camera icon and grid is greyed out.ie,i couldn't get click on both the icons.Could anyone help me to solve this issue.
                           Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It looks like APPLE didn't provide original API for this function.
An easy to use Emoji keyboard for iOS Lib.Has been rewritten with swift, the old Objective-C version on branch OC.In Github this lib named "ISEmojiView".
Hope this Lib used to you.

https://github.com/isaced/ISEmojiView